# Why React state is different from Redux State

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux + React and Im facing a problem that it's getting me crazy.

**Update:** Added [Git repo](https://github.com/timersys/react-darts) instead of pasting here all the code

I'm creating a simple darts scoreboard and saving everything on the redux store. The problem is that when I try to access the data from a render method is not there. Is like state not being propagated to props.

But if I check redux developments tools the data is there. Some screenshots to clarify, where you can see that while in Redux all shots are there on React only the first shot appear.
[image: Redux store with all shots]
[image: React state missing shots]

I thought that could be due to my reducers not using inmutable data but I think they are all ok. Code Im using below:

```
import update from 'react-addons-update';

function players(state = [], action) {

  switch( action.type ){

    case 'ADD_USER_TO_GAME':
        return [
            ...state,
            action.user
        ];
    case 'REORDER_USERS':
      return action.sortedArray;

    case 'REMOVE_USER':
      return [
        ...state.slice( 0, action.index ),
        ...state.slice( action.index + 1 ),
      ];

    case 'SET_ALL_SCORE':
      let new_state = [...state];
      for( let player in new_state ){
          if( new_state[player].ID ) {
              new_state[player].score = action.user_score;
              new_state[player].shots = [];      
          }
      }
      return new_state;

    case 'SAVE_SHOT':
      return [
        ...state.slice( 0, action.user ),
        { ...state[action.user], shots: [...state[action.user].shots, action.shot] },
        ...state.slice( action.user + 1 ),
      ];

    case 'SAVE_SCORE':

      return [
        ...state.slice( 0, action.user ),
        { ...state[action.user], score: action.score },
        ...state.slice( action.user + 1 ),
      ];

    default:
        return state;
  }

}

export default players;
```

Comment: post your component code. As there could be any number of reasons why this is happening

Comment: show how you connect redux store to your component

Comment: @James111  I added the link to github with all the code available. Will be easier than pasting it here.

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating your state directly here:

```
case 'SET_ALL_SCORE':
  let new_state = [...state];
  for( let player in new_state ){
      if( new_state[player].ID ) {
          new_state[player].score = action.user_score;
          new_state[player].shots = [];      
      }
  }
  return new_state;
```

You did clone the state object, but you're mutating it's members directly.

Like this:

```
case 'SET_ALL_SCORE':
  return state.map(player => (
    player.ID
      ? { ...player, score: action.user_score, shots: [] }
      : player
  ));
```

Comment: Hi Jim how can I achieve that result without mutating it? Could you update your answer as I don't see it clearly

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not including the Provider from react-redux in your index.js file. The Provider gives you access to the store in each component. Check out the below example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Routes from './routes';


let storewithmiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxPromise)(createStore)(rootReducer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={storewithmiddleware}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Additionally, you will want to mapStateToProps and subscribe the component to the store with connect() like this:

```
const WelcomePageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(WelcomePage)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {currentUser: state.currentUser}
}
```

(see here: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

It seems like you could really benefit from going through Dan Abramov's tutorials on Redux on egghead.io They are fantastic and clear. Also, do the code along tutorials--they give a great sense of how Redux layers on top of your React app.

Just to note: component state in React is not synonymous with the Redux store.

Comment: I already got that. I just update the question with the git url so you can check all the existing code.

Comment: So glancing at the repo, I think the issue lies in your root reducer (index.js) under combine reducers. Redux is very particular about naming consistencies and set up with combineReducers--it only accepts key value pairs so something like this (and then you reference that part of the store in mapStateToProps in the same way):

Comment: Here is the example: [code] const rootReducer = combineReducers({ userList: users, playerList: players , temp: temp, routing: routerReducer })....then you would access these in mapStateToProps via state.keyname